# Docker - duplicate mount point

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use the [Docker ClamAV image](https://github.com/UKHomeOffice/docker-clamav) in my `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  clamav_updater:
    image: quay.io/ukhomeofficedigital/clamav:latest
    ports:
      - "3310:3310"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/misc/docker/efs_clamav
        target: /var/lib/clamav
```

This service is planned to be the "updater"/"writer". This means it will download updates into `/var/lib/clamav`, and since this is a mounted volume with `source: /home/misc/docker/efs_clamav` - the reader nodes (that will not run the update command) will be able to get the updated files from that folder.

This is all in theory. In practice, when I run this image I get the following error:

> ERROR: for clamav_writer  Cannot create container for service
>   clamav_writer: Duplicate mount point: /var/lib/clamav

I understand that this is due to the fact that the [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/UKHomeOffice/docker-clamav/blob/master/Dockerfile) already set the same directory as a `volume`:

```
VOLUME /var/lib/clamav
```

Is there anyway I can still set that volume in my `docker-compose.yml` file (so that I can set the `source` directory for other readers to read from?

Comment: try `docker-compose down && docker-compose up` command , let me know is it solve your problem ...

Comment: Can't replicate issue from example `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: @RachSharp the container runs fine for you this way? You are able to share the files between `/var/lib/clamav` and your host dir?

Comment: I wasn't checking for actually getting the service to be functional, from your question it seemed like the issue was the startup process failing due to the multiple volume definitions - I didn't get the error message you provided on startup, instead failing later on in the process

Answer (score 58):

A comment from [@hs-dev2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56832097/docker-duplicate-mount-point#comment100217112_56832097) looks like the right answer:

> `docker-compose down`; then `docker compose up`

Comment: This fixes symptoms and not solve the problem. Consider anwer by @4269237

Answer (score 6):

Just in case anyone is still having this issue, it looks like this is the bugfix, which will presumably be released in the version after Docker Desktop v3.4.0:

https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/pull/1782

And the workaround until that makes it into the production docker compose cli is to make sure to use the exact same path (either with or without trailing slash) in the Dockerfile and the docker-compose.yml

Comment: Wow that trailing slash caused me so much trouble!  This answer needs to be upvoted

Comment: I got stuck in the same problem for 4 hours until I came across this comment. Why isn't this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 5):

This issue seams to occur when you have multiple volume declarations mostly in docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile. The solution is to remove VOLUME declaration in your Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml eg.

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    test:
        build: .
        volumes: 
        - /mnt/tmpfs
```

Docker file:

```
FROM alpine:3.4

VOLUME /mnt/tmpfs

CMD /bin/sh
```

I removed the one from the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

For me a combination of both the answers fixed the problem.

Even though I didn't have a duplicate but I had Docker compose in another project with same named volume and same mount path.

The solution was to change the mount path temporarily from

```
volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

to,

```
volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/somethingelse
```

And then I gave `docker compose up` and then `docker compose down`. This cleared the existing mount points.

Finally I reverted my changes to the `yaml`, Now even the old path works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading docker-compose from version 1 (v1.29.2) to version 2 (v2.2.3) fixed it for me.

Note that the installation process is different - and so is the command to run: in version 1, it's `docker-compose`; in 2, it's `docker compose` (i.e. it's a subcommand of `docker`)

Answer (score 0):

This is how the **bind mounts** works for docker/container volume.

> **There are three types of Volumes in the docker/container.**

```
-v volumeID:volumePath // Called as Named Volume

-v "HostMachineAbsolutePath:ContainerVolumePath" // Bind Mounts

-v FilesToIgnoreCopyingFromHostToContainerVolume //Called as anonymous volume
```

> Let's talk about the duplicate mount point error.

This happens because if the named volume path(**volumePath**) is exact the same as bind mounts **ContainerVolumePath**. Both paths should not be the same otherwise you will get a duplicate mount point error.

This how it looks like as an example

```
 docker run -p  30056:30056 -d -v volumeID:volumePath -v "HostMachineAbsolutePath:ContainerVolumePath" -v FilesToIgnoreCopyingFromHostToContainerVolume --name v1C mahesh:v2;
```

Actual command (example):

```
 docker run -p  30056:30056 -d -v dock-volume:/DockerDemo/storage -v "/Users/maheshvirus/DockerDemo/app:/DockerDemo/app" -v /DockerDemo/app/node_modules --name v1C mahesh:v2;
```

> Here is a great example of Named Volumes vs Anonymous Volumes vs Bind
> Mounts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very similar case (`Error response from daemon: fill out specgen: /data: duplicate mount destination`) on linux fedora (where docker is podman) for Redis  `docker.io/redis/redis-stack-server:latest`.

Solved by upgrading to [Docker Compose version v2.15.1](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/v2.15.1).