# docker: Error response from daemon: Duplicate mount point:: Mounting multiple docker volumes on same docker container having same target?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to mount multiple docker volumes into same destination. An example docker run command is here:

```
docker volume create img1-vol 
docker volume create img2-vol 
docker run -it --name somename -d -v img1-vol:/rootdir1  -v img2-vol:/rootdir1 --network somenetwork nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:21.11-tf2-py3
```

Running this command create following error message

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Duplicate mount point: /rootdir1.
```

I have gone through [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56832097/docker-duplicate-mount-point). However, the problem is different. I am trying  to mount multiple docker volume in same target location inside same docker container. Is this possible? Each volume has separate but need to be mount in same  target for unified loading process. I am using windows host machine with docker desktop and WSL-2. I am planning to implement this also in Linux host machine. So, I need an universal solution. Thank in advance.

Comment: Mounting two things on the same mountpoint doesn't make any sense; whichever mount completes last would mask anything else at that mountpoint. If you're expecting to merge the contents of `img1-vol` and `img2-vol`, mounting doesn't work like that.

Comment: (This is true in Unix in general: you can only mount one thing on a directory, and whatever's mounted there hides what was in the underlying filesystem.  This behavior isn't Docker-specific.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mount 2 volumes in a single mount point. The mount point will have last mounted data. if you need to use data from 2 locations in a single directory in docker container, you need to mount those 2 folders to different directories while creating docker and you can create symbolic link in the docker container to point those data to a single directory